# Calling stored procedure from Lua returns an incomplete result

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, lua

I am calling a stored procedure in Lua as followed:

```
res, err, errno, sqlstate = db:query("call icenter.queryUserOTHistorySessionRB(4780,'2016-03-01 00:00:00','2016-04-30 23:59:59');");
```

it returns a single record:

```
[{"LogoffTime":"2016-04-14 07:30:00","user_id":4780,"resource_id":1335,"ResourceName":"WTH5401171","InuseTime":54000,"IdleTime":0,"LogonTime":"2016-04-13 16:30:00"}]
```

But when I call the same procedure in `navicat` for mysql, I get two records:

[image: result]

any ideas?

Comment: Sorry what is the problem? What result is not complete? What is missing? And what is the difference when you use navicat?

Comment: actully, the missing data is the first one, and when I called this procedure in lua script, I  just got one data record, but when I called the same one in navicat, I got two records.

Comment: You have to iterate over the resultset in lua (or in general, any other programming language).

Comment: Are you using LuaSQL?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using LuaSQL. Unfortunately, LuaSQL doesn't guarantee support for stored procedure calls. It's depend on the driver you use.

The MySQL driver has no support for fetching multiple results of stored procedures.

I have created an issue for this on https://github.com/keplerproject/luasql/issues/47